# Testing in-app-billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am trying to test in-app-billing application. Current version on the Android Market doesn't have in-app-billing feature.

When I upload my new version which is having in-app-billing feature as draft, i am getting error message that

"An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later.
There are no in-app products for this application.
New in-app products cannot be added because the current application version does not use the BILLING permission."

I've set all configurations "http://android-sdk.appspot.com/guide/market/billing/index.html"

I want to test in-app-billing before publish it. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is all said in your error message. add BILLING permission in your manifest file and upload your application the market(don't publish it, save as draft). Then add some items in your developers console.

Also, you can try to mention `android.test.purchased` as your product id, in that case market application always answer you, that item has been successfully purchased.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've already added '<service android:name="billing.BillingService" />
    <receiver android:name="billing.BillingReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY" />
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE" />
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>'. Should be billing permission like "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BILLING" />" ?

Comment: Thank you. As I have seen, this is right one: "<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
"