# Difference Between "com.android.vending.BILLING" And "android.permission.BILLING"

Tags: android, android-manifest, in-app-billing, android-permissions, android-billing

Whilst setting up in-app purchases in my app, I came across the fact that there are two permissions related to billing:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BILLING" />
```

What is the difference between these two permissions? It seems most people online are stating to use the first one for in-app purchases but then what is the second one needed for?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776578/testing-in-app-billing

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I know that you have to use the first one, that is not my question. I have in-app purchases working in my app. I just want to know what the second permission is for and when I would need to use it. Clearly Google must have added it for a reason!

Answer (score 3):

For reference, this permission is no longer necessary if you've migrated to `BillingClient` (at the time of writing version 4.0). The following screenshot is from [Android developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/migrate#remove).

[image: Screenshot from Google Documentation]

Answer (score 0):

In-app billing relies on the Google Play application, which handles all communication between your application and the Google Play server. To use the Google Play application, your application must request the proper permission. You this by adding the com.android.vending.BILLING permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

but for

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BILLING" />
```

I dont see if it has any importance unless in a the newest android version they have a library for such permissions without necessarily have to use Google Play App to handle in-app billing. For more info check here http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

Comment: This is just a confusing answer. Did you read the question? OP asks for the difference between the two.